# javascript find select option index based on option text

Tags: javascript, select

I am trying (and failing) to check if an option exists in the select element, based on the option's text:

```
<select id="select">

    <option value="13">I1</option>
    <option value="23">I21</option>
    <option value="954">I33</option>

</select>

var select = document.getElementById('select');

findInvoice(44);

function findInvoice(value_option) {
    
    let x = select.value = [...select.options].findIndex(option => option.text === 'I' + value_option);
    console.log(x);
    
}
```

This does output the -1 value for the index, but it also sets the option index in the select form as well. I strictly only want to check if the index exists or not without selecting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `select.value` when assign value to `x`

Change:

```
let x = select.value = [...select.options].findIndex(option => option.text === 'I' + value_option);
```

to:

```
let x = [...select.options].findIndex(option => option.text === 'I' + value_option);
```

```js
var select = document.getElementById('select');

findInvoice(44);

function findInvoice(value_option) {
    
    let x =  [...select.options].findIndex(option => option.text === 'I' + value_option);
    console.log(x);
    
}
```

```html
<select id="select">

    <option value="13">I1</option>
    <option value="23">I21</option>
    <option value="954">I33</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Super thanks! I am totally blind, I knew I was close :D I will set the response as the correct one in 10 minutes when the system allows me. Cheers!

Comment: @user1286956 You are welcome and glad it solves your problem